# How to capture the traffic of an Android device in Python?

Tags: python, android, traffic

I want to capture traffic of a particular Android device using a Python script. I am doing the same thing for a laptop using "pyshark" that monitors the real-time traffic of laptop for a specific time and then creates a pcap file for it. I want to do the same thing for my Android device. I have tried Tcpdump, scapy and packetsniffer but nothing helped me in capturing the traffic of my Android device.

Ideally I want an analyzer (a python script) that should run in such a fashion that when it is turned on, it continuously monitors the traffic of my Android device. I will have to make something similar to a proxy server but i am stucked how to do it.

pyshark usage for my laptop

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Does your program run with the necessary rights at all? Under Linux and Windows a program needs extended rights to open raw sockets, which are necessary for sniffing. Under Windows there must be some group policy XY setting (I don't know Windows), under Linux the program needs root rights.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about such a policy too. But in the scenario displayed in the picture attached, there is no need for socket programming. I am also okay with passive sniffing.